# JHAT not able to analyze 40 gb dump file even after giving 70 GBs of heap size

Tags: java, heap-dump, jhat

I have requirement to analyze 40 GB of heap dump created by an application. I am using jhat, I have allocated 70 GBs of memory to JHAT to analyze the same but its still throwing **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

Can anyone suggest a way out of this?

Comment: Do you profile your system by watching the heap size increasing? If yes at how many GB is the exception. That will help you solve it

Comment: Hi @gen.Strash , Its standalone application and runs in isolation, so to answer your question, No, system is not being watched.

Comment: There is a way out, split the dump into 8gb sizes and then use JHAT, Atleast it will give you an idea what is going wrong.